# Transforming XML tags within text

Tags: xml, xslt

Let's say I have an XML node like the following:

```
<item id="20">
    <name>Baz</name>
    <description>
        If you liked this, you should check out <related id="5">Foo</related>
        and <related id="7">Bar</related>!
    </description>
<item>
```

When outputting the description via XSLT, I want the `text()` to be rendered such that each of the `<related>` nodes become anchor tags.  How would I go about doing this?

**Edit:** Desired output added per Kirill's request.  I'd like it to look something like this:

> If you liked this, you should check out <a href="/items/5">Foo<a> and <a href="/items/7">Bar<a>!

Comment: Could you provide desired output?

Comment: look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525285/xslt-mixed-content-node , does it help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a template that overrides the default handling for `related` elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="related">
        <a href="/items/{@id}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<item id="20">
    <name>Baz</name>
    <description>
        If you liked this, you should check out <a href="/items/5">Foo</a>
        and <a href="/items/7">Bar</a>!
    </description>
</item>
```

This is a fundamental XSLT pattern. The first template implements the Identity Transform, which copies most nodes through unchanged. The second template overrides the first in the case of `related` elements, converting them to HTML anchors.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar [post](http://%20stackoverflow.com/questions/1525285/xslt-mixed-content-node)
here is an example for your case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="//description" />
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//description">
    <p>
<xsl:apply-templates />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="description//text()">
<xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="description//related">
     <a><xsl:attribute name="href">
    /items/<xsl:value-of select="@id" />
  </xsl:attribute>
<xsl:apply-templates />
    </a>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it's not clean, you'll need to work on it, but it's a start